How to build `boost_stacktrace_backtrace` in vcpkg?
I want to use Boost.stacktrace library to call boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_current_exception().
I read configuration_and_build page but I don't understand what kind of macros is and where to put them.
Firstly, I use the last boost at the moment (v1.85) and I use it in manifest mode.
My vcpkg.json looks like
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
    "name": "test",
    "dependencies": [
        "boost-stacktrace",
        "libbacktrace"
    ]
}

So, to use from_current_exception() I suppose to "set" two macros:

BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK
BOOST_STACKTRACE_ENABLE_BACKTRACE

At first I tried to set them as cmake macros just before project() sentence.
I have tried all compinations I could think up.
set(BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK ON)
set(BOOST_STACKTRACE_ENABLE_BACKTRACE ON)
or even
set(VCPKG_CONFIGURE_MAKE_OPTIONS "BOOST_STACKTRACE_ENABLE_BACKTRACE=ON;-DBOOST_STACKTRACE_ENABLE_BACKTRACE=ON")

Then I decided that it is not cmake options but C/C++ macros and I should add them to preprocessor.
I use custom vcpkg triplet for building and I added next line to the custom triplet file (I build with clang under Linux BTW):
set(VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK=1 -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_ENABLE_BACKTRACE=1")

As a result I see only these libraries in ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux-clang/lib

libbacktrace.a
libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a
libboost_stacktrace_basic.a
libboost_stacktrace_noop.a

And there is no boost_stacktrace_backtrace.a
Also, of course,  I link needed libraries to the project like that:
target_link_libraries(test backtrace dl Boost::headers Boost::stacktrace_addr2line)
So, please, help me to tune cmake+vcpkg that they will build boost_stacktrace_backtrace
